# How can I clamp (clip, restrict) a number to some range?

Tags: python, clamp

I have the following code:

```
new_index = index + offset
if new_index < 0:
    new_index = 0
if new_index >= len(mylist):
    new_index = len(mylist) - 1
return mylist[new_index]
```

Basically, I calculate a new index and use that to find some element from a list. In order to make sure the index is inside the bounds of the list, I needed to write those 2 `if` statements spread into 4 lines. That's quite verbose, a bit ugly... Dare I say, it's quite *un-pythonic*.

**Is there any other simpler and more compact solution?** (and more *pythonic*)

Yes, i know I can use `if else` in one line, but it is not readable:

```
new_index = 0 if new_index < 0 else len(mylist) - 1 if new_index >= len(mylist) else new_index
```

I also know I can chain `max()` and `min()` together. It's more compact, but I feel it's kinda obscure, more difficult to find bugs if I type it wrong. In other words, I don't find it very straightforward.

```
new_index = max(0, min(new_index, len(mylist)-1))
```

---

<sub>See [Pythonic way to replace list values with upper and lower bound (clamping, clipping, thresholding)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41329691/) for specific technique to process values in a Numpy array.</sub>

Comment: If it feels "kinda obscure", make a function out of it?

Comment: Yeah, I can write a function, but that's not the point. The question is how to implement that (either inline or in a function).

Comment: `clamp = lambda value, minv, maxv: max(min(value, maxv), minv)` Using the API from http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#clamp

Answer (score 187, accepted):

This is pretty clear, actually.  Many folks learn it quickly.  You can use a comment to help them.

```
new_index = max(0, min(new_index, len(mylist)-1))
```

Comment: Although I feel it isn't as pythonic as it should be, I also feel this is the best solution we have now.

Comment: `def clamp(n, smallest, largest): return max(smallest, min(n, largest))`

Comment: @csl Folks always provide these small helper functions, but I never know where to put them. `helperFunctions.py`? A separate module? What if this gets littered with various "helper functions" for completely different things?

Comment: I dunno, but if you collect a lot of those and categorize them into sensible modules, why not put on GitHub and create a PyPi package out of it? Would probably become popular.

Comment: @MateenUlhaq `utils.py`

Comment: I prefer to rearrange it so that the values are in order: `min(max(0, new_index), len(mylist)-1)`.

Answer (score 130):

```
sorted((minval, value, maxval))[1]
```

for example:

```
>>> minval=3
>>> maxval=7
>>> for value in range(10):
...   print sorted((minval, value, maxval))[1]
... 
3
3
3
3
4
5
6
7
7
7
```

Comment: +1 for creative usage of `sorted()` built-in. Very compact, but it is just a little bit obscure. Anyway, it's always nice to see other creative solutions!

Comment: Very creative, and actually about as fast as the `min(max())` construction. Very slightly faster in the case that the number is in the range and no swaps are needed.

Comment: Not really faster, since there is an extra heap allocation for the 3-tuple object.

Answer (score 69):

many interesting answers here, all about the same, except... which one's faster?

```
import numpy
np_clip = numpy.clip
mm_clip = lambda x, l, u: max(l, min(u, x))
s_clip = lambda x, l, u: sorted((x, l, u))[1]
py_clip = lambda x, l, u: l if x < l else u if x > u else x
```

```
>>> import random
>>> rrange = random.randrange
>>> %timeit mm_clip(rrange(100), 10, 90)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.02 µs per loop

>>> %timeit s_clip(rrange(100), 10, 90)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.21 µs per loop

>>> %timeit np_clip(rrange(100), 10, 90)
100000 loops, best of 3: 6.12 µs per loop

>>> %timeit py_clip(rrange(100), 10, 90)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 783 ns per loop
```

[paxdiablo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4092565/65696) has it!, use plain ol' python.  The numpy version is, perhaps not surprisingly, the slowest of the lot.  Probably because it's looking for arrays, where the other versions just order their arguments.

Comment: @LenarHoyt it's not that surprising, considering that Numpy's performance is designed around large arrays, not single numbers. Also, it has to convert the integer to an internal datatype first and as it accepts several different kinds of inputs, it probably takes considerable time to figure out what type the input is and what to convert it into. You will see much better Numpy performance if you feed it an array (preferably not a list or tuple, which it has to convert first) of several thousands of values.

Comment: @DustinAndrews you've got that backwards.  1 µs is 10^-6 seconds, 1 ns is 10^-9 seconds.  the python example completes 1 loop in 0.784 µs.  Or at least, it did on the machine I tested it on.  This microbenchmark is about as useful as any other microbenchmark; it can point you away from really bad ideas but probably won't help you much find the actually fastest way to write *useful* code.

Comment: There is a slight overhead on functions' call. I haven't done the benchmarks, but it's quite possible that `mm_clip` and `py_clip` will be equally fast if you use JIT compiler, like PyPy. Except the former is more readable, and readability is more important in Python's philosophy than a slight performance gain most of the time.

Answer (score 44):

See [numpy.clip](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.clip.html):

```
index = numpy.clip(index, 0, len(my_list) - 1)
```

Comment: [The docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.clip.html) say the first parameter of `clip` is `a`, an “array containing elements to clip”. So you would have to write `numpy.clip([index], …`, not `numpy.clip(index, …`.

Comment: @RoryO'Kane: Did you try it?

Comment: Pandas also allows this on Series and DataFrames, and Panels.

Answer (score 30):

Whatever happened to my beloved readable Python language? :-)

Seriously, just make it a function:

```
def addInRange(val, add, minval, maxval):
    newval = val + add
    if newval < minval: return minval
    if newval > maxval: return maxval
    return newval
```

then just call it with something like:

```
val = addInRange(val, 7, 0, 42)
```

Or a simpler, more flexible, solution where you do the calculation yourself:

```
def restrict(val, minval, maxval):
    if val < minval: return minval
    if val > maxval: return maxval
    return val

x = restrict(x+10, 0, 42)
```

If you wanted to, you could even make the min/max a list so it looks more "mathematically pure":

```
x = restrict(val+7, [0, 42])
```

Comment: Putting it in a function is fine (and advised, if you're doing it a lot), but I think `min` and `max` are much clearer than a bunch of conditionals.  (I don't know what `add` is for--just say `clamp(val + 7, 0, 42)`.)

Comment: @GlennMaynard. Not sure that I can agree that min and max are cleaner. The whole point of using them is to be able to stuff more onto one line, effectively making the code less legible.

Answer (score 30):

Chaining `max()` and `min()` together is the normal idiom I've seen. If you find it hard to read, write a helper function to encapsulate the operation:

```
def clamp(minimum, x, maximum):
    return max(minimum, min(x, maximum))
```

Answer (score 21):

This one seems more pythonic to me:

```
>>> def clip(val, min_, max_):
...     return min_ if val < min_ else max_ if val > max_ else val
```

A few tests:

```
>>> clip(5, 2, 7)
5
>>> clip(1, 2, 7)
2
>>> clip(8, 2, 7)
7
```

Answer (score 16):

If your code seems too unwieldy, a function might help:

```
def clamp(minvalue, value, maxvalue):
    return max(minvalue, min(value, maxvalue))

new_index = clamp(0, new_index, len(mylist)-1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Avoid writing functions for such small tasks, unless you apply them often, as it will clutter up your code.

for individual values:

```
min(clamp_max, max(clamp_min, value))
```

for lists of values:

```
map(lambda x: min(clamp_max, max(clamp_min, x)), values)
```

Comment: I disagree with the "avoid writing functions for such small tasks", this kind of advice leads to functions that are 1k lines long. Naming a concept and encapsulating it has it's benefits.