# Most Pythonic way to fit a variable to a range?

Tags: python

Is there a more Pythonic way to achieve this:

```
result = #...real value from elsewhere
max_value = 1
min_value = 0
if result > max_value:
    result = max_value
elif result < min_value:
    result = min_value
return result
```

Not sure how to explain it in words so I hope it's clear. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [min](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#min) and [max](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#max) functions:

```
result = min(max_value, max(min_value, result))
```

Comment: as one of the answers in the [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4092528/how-to-clamp-an-integer-to-some-range-in-python) points out, this is much easier to read if you wrap it in its own function e.g. `clamp(value, min_, max_)`

Answer (score 1):

Here's one option I like:

```
result = max_value if result > max_value else result
result = min_value if result < min_value else result
```

Answer (score 1):

All you need is the `sorted` method

```
result = sorted((min_value,result, max_value))[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

do you really need this part?

```
elif result < min_value:
    result = min_value
```

wouldnt this do just aswell

```
result = #...real value from elsewhere
max_value = 1
min_value = 0
if result >= max_value:
    result = max_value
else:
    result = min_value
return result
```

Comment: No because you forgot to check the case of in the middle!
There are three options min, actual, max. All you have is min, max

Comment: ah sorry thought id put the >= in will edit

Comment: This still only has two end possibilities for `result`. You have an `if` with a regular `else` meaning that one of two paths will always be chosen. IE) `result = max_value` or `result = min_value` will always be called ^ ^

Comment: By OP writing `elif` there are actually **three** paths,`result = max_value` or `result = min_value` or result stays the same