# Python one liner to ensure 0 <= value <= 1?

Tags: python

I was wondering if there's a way of compacting this code:

```
foo = calculate() # 'calculate' is some kind of function which
                  # could return float values less than 0.0 or more than 1.0
                  # It's here only as a (hopefully) clarification
bar = foo * 5 
if bar < 0:
    bar = 0
elif bar > 1:
    bar = 1
else:
    pass # 'bar' has a good value within the "range"
```

I know I could do `bar = max(foo * 5, 0)` or `bar = min(foo * 5, 1)` but... Is there a way of doing this in only one line? Something like `bar = ensure_between(0, foo * 5, 1)` or something like that?

It's not a big deal, I'm just curious.

Thank you in advance **:-)**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4092528/how-to-clamp-an-integer-to-some-range-in-python

Comment: Did you mean `elif foo * 5 > 1: bar = 1`?

Comment: @TigranSaluev Yes, absolutely! Good catch. Bad translation from the actual code into foobars :D Sorry (edited the question as it should've been done)

Comment: @zch: yeeep... you're right! duplicate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A one-liner using min and max, resulting in either a number between 0 and 1, is this what you're looking for?

```
foo = max(0, min(foo, 1))
```

More suited to the example is

```
bar = max(0, min(foo, 1))
```

EDIT: fixed by removing the lists as [soon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1532460/soon) pointed out

Comment: No reason for inner list, just `max(0, min(foo, 1))`