# Pythonic way to replace list values with upper and lower bound (clamping, clipping, thresholding)?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, clip, clamp

I want to replace outliners from a list. Therefore I define a upper and lower bound. Now every value above `upper_bound` and under `lower_bound` is replaced with the bound value. My approach was to do this in two steps using a numpy array.

Now I wonder if it's possible to do this in one step, as I guess it could improve performance and readability.

*Is there a shorter way to do this?*

```python
import numpy as np

lowerBound, upperBound = 3, 7

arr = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])

arr[arr > upperBound] = upperBound
arr[arr < lowerBound] = lowerBound

# [3 3 3 3 4 5 6 7 7 7]
print(arr)
```

---

<sub>See [How can I clamp (clip, restrict) a number to some range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4092528) for clamping individual values, including non-Numpy approaches.</sub>

Comment: While it is nice that there's a compiled `clip` method, there's nothing un-pythonic about your code.  It is a perfectly good use of `numpy`, and just as readable (to an experienced user).  Keep that concept in your toolbox; it works in cases that don't quite fit the `clip` model.

Comment: This operation is generally called ***clamping***, ***clipping*** or else ***thresholding***

Comment: You should use the `clip` method but there is another reason than speed; your code is elegant but creates an intermediate array with `arr > upperBound` which could be an issue if the array gets large.

Comment: @hpaulj thanks for your comment. By the term "pythonic" I meant short and fast. I am aware my solution is not unpythonic, but the `clip()` method is enough for my special use case. The steps 1) doing it on your own 2)  understanding the concept and 3) using a library are a good way to go :)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can use `numpy.clip`:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: arr = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])

In [3]: lowerBound, upperBound = 3, 7

In [4]: np.clip(arr, lowerBound, upperBound, out=arr)
Out[4]: array([3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7, 7])

In [5]: arr
Out[5]: array([3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7, 7])
```

Comment: Hi @arthur, thanks that's exactly what I was looking for! I somehow missed the key word `clip` and didn't find the method myself...

Comment: I wonder how `clip` is written.  It could be doing the same thing, just wrapped in a function call.

Comment: @hpaulj did you find out?

Comment: AFAICT looks like it's in C.

Comment: Like many other functions, `np.clip` is python, but it defers to `arr.clip`, the method.  For regular arrays that method is compiled, so will be faster (about 2x).

Answer (score 14):

For an alternative that doesn't rely on `numpy`, you could always do

```
arr = [max(lower_bound, min(x, upper_bound)) for x in arr]
```

If you just wanted to set an upper bound, you could of course write `arr = [min(x, upper_bound) for x in arr]`.  Or similarly if you just wanted a lower bound, you'd use `max` instead.

Here, I've just applied both operations, written together.

**Edit:** Here's a slightly more in-depth explanation:

Given an element `x` of the array (and assuming that your `upper_bound` is at least as big as your `lower_bound`!), you'll have one of three cases:

1. `x < lower_bound`
2. `x > upper_bound`
3. `lower_bound <= x <= upper_bound`.

In case 1, the `max/min` expression first evaluates to `max(lower_bound, x)`, which then resolves to `lower_bound`.

In case 2, the expression first becomes `max(lower_bound, upper_bound)`, which then becomes `upper_bound`.

In case 3, we get `max(lower_bound, x)` which resolves to just `x`.

In all three cases, the output is what we want.

Comment: just my complaint (no vote), I tend to have to think *really* hard when I see max/min combinations and find them not that readable.

Comment: @djechlin Sure, I don't disagree with that.  On the other hand, the other answer to this point uses `numpy.clip`, which would not be immediately readable to me if I came across it somewhere--I'd probably want to double-check the numpy documentation, or else just guess what it did, and hope that the author got it right.

Comment: What's weird is the nesting. It's a very symmetric operation that consists of "clip once, "clip twice." This is "clip once, then clip that again."

Comment: @djechlin Well...hmm.  I guess to me, "clip once, clip twice" sounds very similar to "clip once, then clip that again", so I'm not sure if I completely understand your objection.  But I do agree that using max/min together imposes some cognitive load...or else, requires some explanation.  So I tried to give a (brief) explanation as well as the code.  (However, I've said a lot more in the comments than I did in my answer, so that suggests that perhaps my answer was a little too brief!)

Comment: Nice one-liner! Always good to have an alternative solution - as I must say that it lacks of readability