# Replace list values above and below thresholds with default value in python?

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to replace "bad values" below and above of thresholds with a default value (e.g. setting them to NaN).
I am unsing a numpy array with 1000k values and more - so performance is an issue.

My prototype does the operation in two steps, is there a pssoibility to do this in one step?

```
import numpy as np

data = np.array([0., 1., 2., 3., 4., 5., 6., 7., 8., 9.])

upper_threshold = 7
lower_threshold = 1
default_value = np.NaN

# is it possible to do this in one expression?
data[data > upper_threshold] = default_value
data[data < lower_threshold] = default_value

print data # [ nan   1.   2.   3.   4.   5.   6.   7.  nan  nan]
```

As commented in this related question ([Pythonic way to replace list values with upper and lower bound (clamping, clipping, thresholding)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41329691/pythonic-way-to-replace-list-values-with-upper-and-lower-bound-clipping))

> Like many other functions, np.clip is python, but it defers to arr.clip, the method. For regular arrays that method is compiled, so will be faster (about 2x). – hpaulj

I hope to find a faster way too, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`boolean-indexing`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-or-mask-index-arrays) in one go with a combined mask -

```
data[(data > upper_threshold) | (data < lower_threshold)] = default_value
```

Runtime test -

```
In [109]: def onepass(data, upper_threshold, lower_threshold, default_value):
     ...:     mask = (data > upper_threshold) | (data < lower_threshold)
     ...:     data[mask] = default_value
     ...: 
     ...: def twopass(data, upper_threshold, lower_threshold, default_value):
     ...:     data[data > upper_threshold] = default_value
     ...:     data[data < lower_threshold] = default_value
     ...:     

In [110]: upper_threshold = 7
     ...: lower_threshold = 1
     ...: default_value = np.NaN
     ...: 

In [111]: data = np.random.randint(-4,11,(1000000)).astype(float)

In [112]: %timeit twopass(data, upper_threshold, lower_threshold, default_value)
100 loops, best of 3: 2.41 ms per loop

In [113]: data = np.random.randint(-4,11,(1000000)).astype(float)

In [114]: %timeit onepass(data, upper_threshold, lower_threshold, default_value)
100 loops, best of 3: 2.74 ms per loop
```

Doesn't look like we are performing any better with the proposed `one-pass-indexing` method. The reason could be that the computation of `OR-ing` of masks is a bit more expensive than directly assigning values with the boolean-indexing itself.

Comment: Ah nice, I tried `data[upper_threshold > data > upper_threshold)] = default_value` which raises an error. This is the way to add more than one condition - thanks a lot.

Comment: That `>...>` only works with scalar Python expressions.  `numpy` requires the explicit `or/and`.  The `()` are also important.