# Pythonic way of setting limits based on list length

Tags: python, list, if-statement, code-formatting

I want to limit the height of a tkinter widget  based on a length of a list. For this, i want to set 5 as a lower and 10 as an upper limit. The height should be 10 if my list exceeds 10 elements, 5 when there are equal or less than 5 elements, and the exact amount of elements if the list is in that range. I am wondering if there is a more pythonic way than this:

```
if 5 <= len(self.content) <= 10:
    lb_height = len(self.content)
elif len(self.content) <= 5:
    lb_height = 5
else:
    lb_height = 10
```

Comment: Something like `min(max(len(self.content), 5), 10)`

Comment: thanks, thats convenient :)

Answer (score 1):

This answer does something similar: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4092550/11652155

For your case, you'd just change the lower and upper limits:

```py
lb_height = max(5, min(len(self.content), 10))
```

Comment: Don't link to another answer, flag as a duplicate

Comment: thanks guys, and sorry for the duplicate